# onblur deletes data when submit, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following script.

```
<input style="color: #ccc" type="text" value="something" name="country"  
onFocus="if (this.value == 'something') {
    this.value='';this.style.color='black';}" 
onblur="if (this.value != 'something') {
    this.value='something'}" />
<input  type="submit" value="save"  />
```

On blur, the input value is set to a default value, as it's supposed to. When i click on submit button, the value is also set to "something"; when submitting, i need to post the data the user wrote in the input, rather than the default.

What can I do if I want that when I click on submit button, the input value doesn't change?
thanks

Comment: Works for me. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario it can't work, becouse onblur includes and clicking on submit. i just need to avoid it.

Comment: the wording of the question wasn't very clear. I believe it now better describes the behavior you want. If not, you can edit the question to clarify.

Comment: do you ever want to submit the default? What is the overall purpose of setting the value of the input to a default?

Comment: keep in mind that if you click on the submit, unless you don't use **AJAX** OR you don't store the **value in DB** OR use **COOKIE** you can't get back the typed value!!! hope this make all thing clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after

```
 <input style="color: #ccc" type="text" value="something" name="country"  
onFocus="if (this.value == 'something') {
    this.value='';this.style.color='black';}"
  onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'something'}" />
<input  type="submit" value="save"  />
```

Comment: even if the value not empty,but not "something" i want to get back it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your onblur function might be a little off. The way you currently have it is replacing any value the user enters.  Try this:

```
onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='something'}"
```

In other words, only put "something" back into the text field if we left it blank.

Comment: @Greg W i want another. if user insert some text, but click not on submit button, i want to get back my default text.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the value of the input to hide what the user wrote, it's simpler to change the input type between a text input and a password input.

```
<input style="color: #ccc" type="password" name="country"
       onFocus="this.type='text'; this.style.color=''"
       onblur="this.type='password'" />
```

If you want the input to display the default value when it doesn't have focus, but submit the value the user last typed, you can use a hidden input. Since JS might be disabled/unavailable, you'll either need to change the inputs' names in JS or resolve which input to get the value from server-side.

```
<input type="hidden" name="country_actual" />
<input style="color: #ccc" type="password"
       onFocus="this.value='';this.style.color='black';" 
       onblur="this.form.elements.counter.value=this.value; this.value='something'" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms[document.forms.length-1].elements.country.name = '';
    document.forms[document.forms.length-1].elements.country_actual.name = 'country';
</script>
```

If you want to keep the user typed value only when the focus switches from the input to the submit button, it's difficult to impossible. When focus switches, the blur event may fire before the focus event (depending on the browser), so you can't use that to check the newly focused element, which you could otherwise do with [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.activeElement). Furthermore, on webkit based browsers, buttons (whether `<input>` or `<button>` elements) don't seem to get focus.